# Looking for ASIC resistant hash functions

Tags: hash

I am looking for some sort of hash function that is resistant to ASIC so something that works well on a CPU but is not very good with other hardware like a GPU or ASIC

Comment: Most hash functions are completely sequential. Do you mean maybe password hashing for which a brute force or dictionary attack is launched? The problem with that is that they are fully parallel as you can test each password individually.

Comment: I am looking for some sort of hash function that asic resistant sort of sorry for bad wording

Comment: Is this slowdown for an implementation that does multiple cores to accelerate a single hash, or for parallel evaluations of multiple hashes?

Comment: i worded it wrong i was looking for some sort of hash function that was hard to implement for asics sorry for bad wording i will edit the title to better fit my search

Comment: Try Argon2 with good parameters? Keep in mind that ASIC is a too generic term. And [Equihash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equihash)